# How to find the array index with a value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexof

Say I've got this

```js
imageList = [100,200,300,400,500];
```

Which gives me

`[0]100 [1]200` etc.

Is there any way in JavaScript to return the index with the value?

I.e. I want the index for **200**, I get returned **1**.

Comment: Excellent answer here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/array-containsobj-in-javascript

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Answer (score 370, accepted):

You can use [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf):

```
var imageList = [100,200,300,400,500];
var index = imageList.indexOf(200); // 1
```

You will get -1 if it cannot find a value in the array.

Comment: you can use https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf or any Javascript framework to fix that.

Comment: Have just found it won't work in IE8.  What's my alternative?

Comment: @voigtan How do I add this to my JS?

Comment: I've done it, thanks.  IE will one day catch up with modern times!

Comment: Also won't work in recent IE if in compatibility mode

Comment: var arrayPosition = $.inArray( value, Array ); will work in all versions of IE

Answer (score 103):

For **objects array** use `map` with `indexOf`:

```js
var imageList = [
   {value: 100},
   {value: 200},
   {value: 300},
   {value: 400},
   {value: 500}
];

var index = imageList.map(function (img) { return img.value; }).indexOf(200);

console.log(index);
```

---

In modern browsers you can use [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex):

```js
var imageList = [
   {value: 100},
   {value: 200},
   {value: 300},
   {value: 400},
   {value: 500}
];

var index = imageList.findIndex(img => img.value === 200);

console.log(index);
```

Its part of ES6 and [supported by](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-Array.prototype_methods) Chrome, FF, Safari and Edge

Comment: Note that findIndex is not implemented in IE 11

Comment: @Bindrid it is written in the answer see _"Its part of ES6 and supported by Chrome, FF, Safari and (Unfortunately only) IE edge"_

Answer (score 18):

Use jQuery's function
[jQuery.inArray](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/)

```
jQuery.inArray( value, array [, fromIndex ] )
(or) $.inArray( value, array [, fromIndex ] )
```

Comment: Was going to use the code marked as the correct answer but it seems that that code wont work in all versions of IE. This answer works in all versions of IE but I changed the code slightly: 
var arrayPosition = $.inArray( value, Array ); works perfectly

Comment: jQuery ≠ Javascript

Answer (score 17):

Here is an another way find value index in complex array in javascript. Hope help somebody indeed.
Let us assume we have a JavaScript array as following,

```
var studentsArray =
     [
    {
    "rollnumber": 1,
    "name": "dj",
    "subject": "physics"
   },
   {
   "rollnumber": 2,
  "name": "tanmay",
  "subject": "biology"
   },
  {
   "rollnumber": 3,
   "name": "amit",
   "subject": "chemistry"
   },
  ];
```

Now if we have a requirement to select a particular object in the array. Let us assume that we want to find index of student with name Tanmay.

We can do that by iterating through the array and comparing value at the given key.

```
function functiontofindIndexByKeyValue(arraytosearch, key, valuetosearch) {

    for (var i = 0; i < arraytosearch.length; i++) {

    if (arraytosearch[i][key] == valuetosearch) {
    return i;
    }
    }
    return null;
    }
```

You can use the function to find index of a particular element as below,

```
var index = functiontofindIndexByKeyValue(studentsArray, "name", "tanmay");
alert(index);
```

Answer (score 10):

Use indexOf

```
imageList.indexOf(200)
```

Answer (score 8):

how about `indexOf` ?

```
alert(imageList.indexOf(200));
```

Answer (score 7):

`Array.indexOf` doesnt work in some versions of internet explorer - there are lots of alternative ways of doing it though ... see this question / answer : [How do I check if an array includes an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/array-containsobj-in-javascript)

Comment: according to this page https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf you need Internet Explorer 9 for this feature (I almost wrongly assumed we were just talking IE 6 here)

Comment: @Simon_Weaver on that page you linked there is a polyfill for all browsers using JavaScript 1.6 and up

Answer (score 6):

When the lists aren't extremely long, this is the best way I know:

```
function getIndex(val) {
    for (var i = 0; i < imageList.length; i++) {
        if (imageList[i] === val) {
            return i;
        }
    }
}

var imageList = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500];
var index = getIndex(200);
```

Answer (score 6):

It is possible to use a `ES6` function `Array.prototype.findIndex`.

[MDN says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex):

> The `findIndex()` method returns the index of **the first element in the array that satisfies** the provided testing function. Otherwise -1 is returned.

```
var fooArray = [5, 10, 15, 20, 25];
console.log(fooArray.findIndex(num=> { return num > 5; }));

// expected output: 1
```

**Find an index by object property.**

To find an index by object property:

```
yourArray.findIndex(obj => obj['propertyName'] === yourValue)
```

For example, there is a such array:

```
let someArray = [
    { property: 'OutDate' },
    { property: 'BeginDate'},
    { property: 'CarNumber' },
    { property: 'FirstName'}
];
```

Then, code to find an index of necessary property looks like that:

```
let carIndex = someArray.findIndex( filterCarObj=> 
    filterCarObj['property'] === 'CarNumber');
```

Answer (score 4):

### **In a multidimensional array**.

---

*Reference array:*

```
var array = [
    { ID: '100' },
    { ID: '200' },
    { ID: '300' },
    { ID: '400' },
    { ID: '500' }
];
```

**Using `filter` and `indexOf`:**

```
var index = array.indexOf(array.filter(function(item) { return item.ID == '200' })[0]);
```

**Looping through each item in the array using `indexOf`:**

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var item = array[i];
    if (item.ID == '200') { 
        var index = array.indexOf(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take on it, seems like most peoples solutions don't check if the item exists and it removes random values if it does not exist.

First check if the element exists by [looking for it's index](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp).
If it does exist, remove it by its index using the [splice](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp) method

```
elementPosition = array.indexOf(value);

if(elementPosition != -1) {
  array.splice(elementPosition, 1);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
// Instead Of 
var index = arr.indexOf(200)

// Use 
var index = arr.includes(200);
```

**Please Note**: Includes function is a simple instance method on the array and helps to easily find if an item is in the array(including NaN unlike indexOf)

Comment: In addition to this only telling you if it exists, instead of getting the index/item, be cognizant of the compatibility (i.e. no IE): https://caniuse.com/#search=includes

Comment: [`includes` returns a Boolean indicating if the array contains the value specified](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).