# How to match a variable value against an array of values in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, match

I have an array of values with names:

```
names = ['Jim', 'Jack', 'Fred']
```

I have also received a value from a function, which is a name in string form, such as:

```
returnedValue = 'Jim'
```

How can I run the returnedValue string against the values of the names array and test for a match?

My feeling is that you would want to use the .filter method of the array prototype but I can't conceive of how to do it that way.

Comment: Use **[indexOf](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp)**

Comment: `names.indexOf(returnedValue)`

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript find array index with value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7346827/javascript-find-array-index-with-value)

Comment: filter() would be used to count or find all the matches instead of just the first (or last via lastIndexOf())

Comment: names.contains works in es6

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is an indexOf method that all arrays have (except in old version of Internet Explorer) that will return the index of an element in the array, or -1 if it's not in the array:

```
if (yourArray.indexOf("someString") > -1) {
    //In the array!
} else {
    //Not in the array
}
```

If you need to support old IE browsers, you can use polyfill this method using the code in the MDN article.

Copied from https://stackoverflow.com/a/12623295/2934820

Comment: I was looking allll over the internet for this. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

the Array.indexOf method will return a value with the position of the returned value, in this case 0, if the value is not in array you'd get back -1 so typically if you wanna know if the returnedValue is in the array you'd do this
    if (names.indexOf(returnedValue) > -1) return true;
Or you can do ~~ like Mr. Joseph Silber kindly explains in another thread

Answer (score -1):

Check out this link on dictionaries
https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp
If you have a variable whose value would match a string in the dictionary you can set a variable to equal that value. Here is a snip from some of my own code`

```
global element1
element1 = 1
elementdict = {
"H": 1.008,
"He": 4.00,
"Li": 6.49,
"Be": 9.01,
"B": 10.81,
"C": 12.01,
"N": 14.01,
"O": 16.00,
"F": 19.00,
"Ne": 20.18,
"Na": 22.99,
"Mg": 24.30
}
element1 = input("Enter an element to recieve its mass")
element1 = elementdict[element1]
print(element1)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! You might want to review [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). The answer you provided is for Python and the question was about JavaScript.