# Check if user inputs a week or weekend day, using for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, while-loop

sorry if this question feels redundant, but I haven`t been able to find the answer with this method. It doesn`t get answered on the link provided.
 I have been trying to make a Javascript program that checks if the input from the user is a Week day or weekend. It has to be done with for or do while loops.

I want my program to check if the user input is in the array, if it is, the program should be able to tell if it`s a working day or weekend.

My problem: It always returns working day, even if I put Saturday or Sunday.

this is tagged as Javascript, but works for any language since it`s basic stuff.

Here`s my code so far

```
var input = prompt("Enter a day of the week");
var day = ["monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday", "saturday", "sunday"];

for (var i = 0; i <= day.length; i++)
{
    if(input >= day[5]){
        console.log("It´s weekend!"); {break;}
    }else
    {
        console.log("It´s a working day");

    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find the array index with a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7346827/how-to-find-the-array-index-with-a-value)

Comment: What's your input? Is it a number or a full text (eg. Monday)

Comment: My input is always a day, like "saturday" "sunday" "monday", etc. it returns working day always, even with numbers.

Comment: `console.log('It´s '+(/(satur|sun)day/.test(prompt('Enter a day of the week'))?'weekend!':'a working day'))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you have to use a `for` loop. The following code should work:

```
var input = prompt("Enter a day of the week");
var workingday = ["monday", "tuesday", "Wensday", "thursday", "friday"];
var weekend = ["saturday", "sunday"]

if (workingday.indexOf(input) != -1) {
     console.log("It´s a working day!");
} else if (weekend.indexOf(input) != -1) {
     console.log("It´s weekend!");
} else {
     console.log("Invalid input!");
}
```

By the way, you misspelled "Wensday".
To use `for` loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < day.length; i++)  {
    if (day[i] == input)  {
        console.log((i >= 5) ? "It's weekend!" : "It's a working day");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your input is a string and your days are an array so you can't do a greater-than comparison in your if statement.

Instead, you need to find at what index (number) the day the input matches. There are already an array method called [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf?v=example) finding the index of an item in an array. You can  then see if that day number is greater than or equal to the days of the weekend.

```
var dayNumber = days.indexOf(input);
if (dayNumber >= 5) {
  // it's the weekend
}
```

However, if you have to use a for loop, you can simulate what `indexOf()` does. It works by increasing an number `dayNumber` each loop and then using that number to index into the `days` array. You can then compare the value at that index with your `input`. If it matches, you know what day number it is and can see if it's greater than or equal to the days of the weekend.

```
for (var dayNumber = 0; dayNumber < days.length; dayNumber++) {
  // check if the input matches the current index of the array
  if (input == days[dayNumber]) {
    // if it does, check if the day number is on the weekend
    if (dayNumber >= 5) {
      // it's the weekend
    }
  }
}
```

This can be made more compact using an "and operator" `&&` to combine the two nested if statements.

```
if (input == days[dayNumber] && dayNumber >= 5) {
  // it's the weekend
}
```