# React: find string in array and rename it

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I rename an element of an array if this element contains a given string?

So e.g. I have an  array in my state:

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            array: ["stack", "overflow", "question"],
        }
}
```

and now I wanna replace the string `question` with e.g. `answer`. So I could easily do this if the index of `question` is always the same but how can I replace `question` with `answer` if question always have an other index? This should be done in the most efficient way. Hope anyone can help me. 
Thanks

Comment: [Find the index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7346827/how-to-find-the-array-index-with-a-value) then change it. Or use a simple loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HERE YOU GO :

This is just a code snippet, you can apply your logic as well, I have just compare exact string for simplicity of code.

```js
console.log(
        ["stack", "overflow", "question"]
        .map(str => str==="question" ? "answer" : str)
)
```

---

In react, you can use it like

```
this.setState((state) => {
    array : state.array.map(str => str==="question" ? "answer" : str)
})
```

Comment: OP wants the array element in the original replaced. This code creates a new array.

Comment: @dww, in react you can't mutate state directly, you need new copy of that, so this is perfectly fine for react. as you can see the array is inside the state

Answer (score 1):

You could use indexOf to find out what index the item is at and then replace that.

Something like:

```js
const arr = ["stack", "overflow", "question"];

function replaceStr(newStr, str, arr){
  if(arr.indexOf(str) >= 0){
    arr[arr.indexOf(str)] = newStr;
  }
  return arr;
}

console.log(replaceStr("Hello", "question", arr))
```